# Conditional expectation - example based on definition

Tags: conditional-expectation

$$
\Omega=\{a,b,c\}, \mathcal{F}=2^{\Omega}\\
P(\{a\})=P(\{b\})=P(\{c\})=\frac{1}{3}\\
X(a)=1, X(b)=2, X(c)=15
$$

$$\mathcal{G}=\sigma (\{a\})=\{\phi, \{a\}, \{a,b,c\}, \{b,c\}\}\}$$

I have to find $E(X|\mathcal{G})$.
I have a solution:
$$E(X|\mathcal{G})(a)=1\\
E(X|\mathcal{G})(b)=E(X|\mathcal{G})(c)=\frac{17}{2}
$$

But I don't know exactly how the solution was found - could somebody give me the formula used here?

Answer (score 0):

The formula that you have to use is the following:
$$\mathbb{E}[X \mid \sigma (B)]=\begin{cases}
\mathbb{E}[X \mid B] & \mbox{if } \omega\in B \\
\mathbb{E}[X \mid B^c] & \mbox{if } \omega \in B^c \\
\end{cases}.$$

In this particular case we have that:
$$\mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{G}]=\mathbb{E}[X \mid \sigma ( \{ a \})]=\begin{cases}
\mathbb{E}[X \mid \{ a \}] & \mbox{if } \omega=a \\
\mathbb{E}[X \mid \{b,c\}] & \mbox{if } \omega \neq a \\
\end{cases}$$
So using the formula of mean value respect a specific event we have:
$$\mathbb{E}[X \mid \{a\}]=\frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(\{a \})}(X(a)\mathbb{P}(\{a \}))=1,$$
and
$$\mathbb{E}[X \mid \{b,c\}]=\frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(\{b,c \})}(X(b)\mathbb{P}(\{b \})+X(c)\mathbb{P}(\{c \})=\frac{3}{2}(2\cdot\frac{1}3+15\cdot\frac13)=\frac{17}{2}.$$
In conclusion 
$$\mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{G}]=\begin{cases}
1 & \mbox{if } \omega=a \\
\frac{17}{2} & \mbox{if } \omega \neq a \\
\end{cases}$$